# Besides ls, cd, mv, cp, chmod/chown, sudo and vi, what are the most useful command line utilities to master?

Tags: linux, mac, bash, unix, shell

Using Bash, but any shell is fine.

Comment: get unix encyclopedia

Comment: Really? Closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as Arcege's list, learn how to use:

- find
- grep
- tr
- cut

Plus Bash built-ins like

- while
- for
- if

Also learn about [pipes, redirection](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial), [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters), [brace expansion](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-shell-brace-expansion/), [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html), [history](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/history.html#SEC2) and [completion](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/316).

oh and...

- man

Answer (score 2):

sed       - file manipulation, e.g. `sed -e '/<foo>/,/<\/foo>/{;s/bar/widget/;}' xyzzy.xml`

awk       - file manipulation, my favorite idiom is `du -sk * | awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum}'`

less      - paginator

tail -f   - stream viewer, great for dozens of logs; `tail -f logs/*.{log,err,out}`

Answer (score 0):

To Arcege's list I'd add:

```
watch
```

as in

```
watch -d -n 'ls -al File*; wc -l File1'
```

(of course replace File*|File1 with whatever)

Answer (score 0):

Those commands that you listed "ls, cd, mv, cp, ..." are all just programs that happen to be installed on every unix and linux system. I often take a look around in the places where these programs reside like `/bin, /sbin, /usr/bin, /usr/sbin`. Then I use the `man` or `info` command to get more details on each of those commands in those directories. Use `man man` to get more details on the man command (press q to quit).

The ones I often use are `grep, ssh, dd, nmap, ifconfig, route, and iptables (the firewall)`. I have by no means mastered iptables or grep. There are so many commands that each do different things and are each useful in their own way. It is difficult to pick the "most useful" ones. The ones that you consider most useful will depend on which programs best help with what you do most often.

Comment: you could use `grep` every day for many many years, `iptables` however, you will rarely have to play with.

Comment: @slomojo True grep defnetly stands out as one of the big ones that can be applied to just about anything.